# Changing Directive that renders HighChart using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular Directives to render Highcharts visuals and am trying to change the directive used based on User input. For testing, attempting to switch between line and column charts.
The directives are:

```
myApp.directive('columnChart', function () {
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    initChart();
    function initChart() {
        var chartConfig = {
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: [{
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Y Axis Label'
                    },
            }],
                series: [{
                    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
                }]
        };
        var chart = $(element).highcharts(chartConfig);
    }
};
});
```

and

```
myApp.directive('lineChart', function () {
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
     initChart();

 function initChart() {
        var chartConfig = {
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: [{
                min: 0,
                //max:200,
                title: {
                    text: 'Y Axis Label'
                    },
            }],
                series: [{
                    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
                }]
        };
        var chart = $(element).highcharts(chartConfig);
    }
};
});
```

I have a simple test page with buttons that change the directive:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="setLineChart()">Set Line Chart</button>
    <button ng-click="setColumnChart()">Set Column Chart</button>
    <div id="container" column-Chart style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</div>
```

and the code to set the Directive:

```
$scope.setLineChart = function() {
    var docElement = document.getElementById("container");
    var scope = angular.element(docElement).scope();
    var element = angular.element(docElement);
    element.html('<div id="chartContainer" line-Chart style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>');
    console.log("element: " , element);
    $compile(element)(scope);
};
```

Clicking on the Set Line Chart button causes the Directive for the line chart to get called, but the chart still resolved as a column chart.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MFRTest/xsadzv4f/12/

I appreciate any insight into what I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the AngularJS framework, avoid manipulating DOM in controllers. The framework [separates concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) to make the app more easily understood, debugged, tested, and maintained.

Instead have a directive that create [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com) based on the Model furnished by the Controller:

```
app.directive("highchart", function() {
  return {
    link: postLink
  }
  function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.highchart, function (chartConfig) {
      elem.highcharts(chartConfig);
    }, true)
  }
})
```

Usage:

```
<button ng-click="$ctrl.chart = $ctrl.lineChart">Set Line Chart</button>
<button ng-click="$ctrl.chart = $ctrl.colChart">Set Column Chart</button>

<div highchart="$ctrl.chart" 
     style="min-width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
```

[The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/7TuUqhlghTjXTxSWVpay?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])

.directive("highchart", function() {
  return {
    link: postLink
  }
  function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.highchart, function (chartConfig) {
      elem.highcharts(chartConfig);
    })
  }
})

.controller("ctrl", function() {
  this.colChart = {
        chart: {
          type: 'column',
          zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
          text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
          ]
        },
        yAxis: [{
          min: 0,
          //max:200,
          title: {
            text: 'Y Axis Label'
          },
        }],
        series: [{
          data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
      };
  this.lineChart = {
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: [{
                min: 0,
                //max:200,
                title: {
                    text: 'Y Axis Label'
                    },
            }],
                series: [{
                    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
                }]
        };
})
```

```html
    <script src="//unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/highcharts"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
    
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as $ctrl">
    <h3>Highchart Directive DEMO</h3>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.chart = $ctrl.lineChart">
      Set Line Chart
    </button>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.chart = $ctrl.colChart">
      Set Column Chart
    </button>
    <div highchart="$ctrl.chart" 
         style="min-width: 300px; height: 180px; margin: 0 auto">
    </div>
  </body>
```